# How to insert javascript code into Jupyter

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, anaconda, jupyter

I'm trying to insert this script on custom.js. I changes to color red all the negative currency.

I want it to be applied to all pandas dataframes printed on Jupyter. After adding it to all custom.js available on jupyter/anaconda folders, it still didn't change anything. Can someone help me?

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    //get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

    //check for 'one' and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
    if (currentText.includes("$ -"))
        node.style.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%%javascript
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    //get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

    //check for 'one' and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
    if (currentText.includes("$ -"))
        node.style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as I put it on the last cell. Is it possible that jupyter will load this script every time I run a cell?